# How to use a sh variable in a gcp sql query command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sh, google-cloud-spanner

I've a sh script which runs a sql query in a gcp > spanner db.

The query works fine. I need to incorporate in the sql-query code the value of one of the variable `ID` which is declared in the sh script.

What would be the right syntax for this case?

```
export DATABASE='my_db'
export ID='my_id'


    gcloud spanner databases execute-sql $DATABASE  \
        --instance=stable-id  \
        --sql='SELECT * FROM $ID' \
        --format=json > spanner-$ID.json
```

this variable `$ID` works fine in the script, but doesn't in the line where i call the query

```
        --sql='SELECT * FROM $ID' \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double-quotes instead of single-quotes for this to work.

```
export DATABASE='my_db'
export ID='my_id'


    gcloud spanner databases execute-sql $DATABASE  \
        --instance=stable-id  \
        --sql="SELECT * FROM $ID" \
        --format=json > spanner-$ID.json
```

Should work.